# All routes working fine but the new created route return 404 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes

Am trying to add a route in my api.php in laravel, whereas all other api are working fine but newly added api is not working returning 404.

```
Route::get('products','Api\ProductsController@index');
Route::get('products/trending','Api\ProductsController@trendingProducts');
```

Products return data but when searched for trending it returns 404. Tried clearing route cache and checking in route list. The route exist in routelist. Even the function in controller also existl.

Controller Code :

```
public function trendingProducts(){
    echo "i";        
}
```

Confused by the unexpected behaviour. Any help will be gratefull. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the controllermethod perform an `abort()` or has a `findOrFail()` in it? Have you cleared your routes cache? `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Maybe show what's inside your controllers

Comment: Show whats inside your controllers so we can help you more

Comment: hi @HaroutFMD added controller code just returning i form there.

Comment: Dint know how it happen and why but places that url all above and it started working any idea why so @harout

Comment: yourdomain/api/products/trending is 404?   You said "searching" are you posting to that endpoint and need Route::post()  instead of Route::get()?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
href="{{url('')}}/api/products/trending"
```